# IPv6 address not available from outside

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ipv6, ping

Since Hetzner pretty much doesn't give out any IPv4 addresses, no matter what the reason is, I decided to give IPv6 a try.

These is the assigned IP address subnet mask

```
IPs: 2a01:4f8:190:5112:: /64
Gateway: fe80::1
Useable IP addresses:
2a01:4f8:190:5112::2 to 2a01:4f8:190:5112:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

First I added IP with

```
ip -6 addr add 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2/64 dev eth0
```

added this block to /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1
```

and restarted networking.

When I attempt to ping this IP from the server, it pings ok.

```
root@server ~ # ping6 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2
PING 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2(2a01:4f8:190:5112::2) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
```

however any attempts to do pinging from outside the server, result in

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I am new to configuring IPv6 addresses so it's possible I may have forgotten something.
I am running Ubuntu 13.10 if it matters.

Output from ip6tables -L -n -v

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 10383 packets, 2639K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 13967 packets, 1119K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Thank you very much in advance, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the output from `ip6tables -L -n -v` into your question?

Comment: Sure. Updated my question.

Comment: Ah, OK, that's not it, then!

Comment: What about pinging out from the server?  `ping6 -n www.free.fr`.

Comment: Works perfectly well.

Comment: Does the computer where you are pinging from have IPv6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.  This just in, from my v6-enabled server:

```
[me@lory mail]$ ping6 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2
PING 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2(2a01:4f8:190:5112::2) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=21.2 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=21.1 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:190:5112::2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=21.1 ms
```

I suspect the problem may be ipv6 on the machine you're PINGing **from**, rather than the one you're PINGing **to**.  But in any case, that's not what you asked; to answer the question you asked, your server's ipv6 is set up just fine.

Though if I were you, I'd put up some kind of v6-firewall ruleset fairly quickly!

**Edit:** Is it supported?  Well, that sort of depends on whether you've set it up!  v6 works perfectly well, but here in the UK, despite being fairly standard in data centres it's not yet common amongst domestic ISPs.  There are some who can do it (I use one), but you often have to ask for it.  Even if you have one that supports it, and you ask for it and get it, your gateway device will need to be told about it, and will have to run some kind of route advertisement daemon and either hand out addresses or support stateless v6 address autoconfiguration so that LAN clients get the right addresses and routes.

So: yes, it can be supported, but both your and your ISP have to be involved.  It doesn't somehow magically all work out of the box, with free sparkle ponies as an added bonus.

By the way, may I thank you for **not** redacting your ip addresses in this question?  It was a **very great deal easier to answer as a result of your putting in the real addresses**.

Comment: This makes sense.

I just tried to do pinging to this address from 3 different servers and 4 separate PC's (3 ubuntu and 1 windows), none of them were able to ping IP address, is IPv6 support really this poor at the moment?

Comment: @Screatch Yes, it really is that poor. According to Google, IPv6 deployment on clients is at about 3% (http://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html). According to my calculations we needed to reach that point about 13 years ago in order to complete the upgrade to IPv6 on time (http://kasperd.net/~kasperd/transition). It is almost certainly your ISP, you have to blame for not having IPv6 on your client machines.

Comment: Never through its this bad.

Thank you for thorough explanations. Looks like its a little bit too early to move to IPv6 just yet.

Comment: It's an excellent time to go dual-stack, and we all should.  It's too early to go single-stack v6, though, except where you are servicing a known v6-enabled client population.

Comment: @Screatch it may be a bit too early to go IPv6-only. But it is not too early to go dual stack, everybody should have done so years ago. As far as I know, Hetzner is still providing one IPv4 address, so what is it you need to do, for which that one IPv4 address is insufficient? Maybe IPv6-only is an option for some of the things you want to do, but not for all of it.

Comment: Hetzner no longer gives out IPv4 address, no matter if its for SSL uses or for DNS, or if your scripts need separate IP.

There is seriously no more legitimate reason for receiving more than one IP address.

Comment: That was kasperd's point.  What exactly is your business need for a second v4 address?

Comment: APNIC (Asia-Pacific) and RIPE NCC (Europe, the Middle East and parts of Central Asia) have run out of unallocated IPv4 addresses a long time ago (2012). ISPs cannot get any new addresses (unless they find someone who want to sell their addresses, but prices will be high), so they will be *very* careful with giving addresses to customers. ARIN (North America) is going to run out soon as well. Countries like Romania, Switzerland and Belgium have many residential IPv6 users, but other countries are far far behind. So we are in a situation where we are out of IPv4, but cannot go IPv6-only yet :(

Comment: Sander, I don't disagree we're coming to that point, but RIPE simply isn't out of unallocated addresses yet.  [This graph](http://www.ripe.net/internet-coordination/ipv4-exhaustion/ipv4-available-pool-graph) shows that they had slightly less than 14 million unallocated v4 addresses as of 28/4/14.  What they have been on since Sep 2012 is their last `/8`, which triggers more draconian allocation policies (PA-space to LIRs only in `/22`s, no PI-space).  We are not out of ipv4 yet, but as the clamp-down filters through the the NSPs and ISPs, their incentive to supply ipv6 increases - I hope!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use IPv6, you need to have it not only on the server, but also on the client. If your ISP is not willing to do their job and upgrade their network, you can look into using a 6in4 tunnel. There are different providers, some do well in some areas, others do well in other areas. Overall my feeling is that [Hurricane Electric](https://tunnelbroker.net/) is the best choice.